# Does AllJoyn Router support discovery of remote services running on wired local network

Tags: linux, windows, alljoyn

Client and server running on different computers that connected to local area Network. Can we use Alljoyn to publish the server to be auto discover by clients running on a remote machine connected to same local area network.

All machines are running Linux and connected to each other via local area network instead WiFi.

Answer (score 3):

The AllJoyn framework runs on the local network.

As of [16.04](https://allseenalliance.org/framework/download), It currently supports;

- Wi-Fi,
- Ethernet,
- Serial,
- Power Line (PLC) transports.

[image: AllJoyn Router Module Architecture]

Comment: Bluetooth hasn't been supported for years.

Comment: @RyJones can you provide any links discussing that? I can't imagine why it would have been removed?

Comment: @TimBertalot it was removed because support on Android was hardware dependent and not robust. [here are the current transports](https://allseenalliance.org/alliance/faqs/what-transport-layers-does-alljoyn-work-wifi-bluetooth-nfc-zigbee-etc). [some of the earliest Alliance bugs were to remove remaining Bluetooth references](https://jira.allseenalliance.org/browse/ASACORE-39?jql=text%20~%20%22bluetooth%22)

Answer (score 2):

yes, Alljoyn supports this scenario

Answer (score 0):

The requirement for discovery is that your machines are all on the same [broadcast domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_domain).